# Does ng messages set form data to 'undefined' if using $error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, message

I am using ng messages to set requirements on data including: minlength, maxlength, required.

I am still allowing the formData to be returned using a form button.

When I look at the data, it's being returned from the form as 'undefined'.

If a field fails ng messages, does the value for that field change to undefined?

Comment: No.. `ng-messages` doesn''t modify data, it only displays validation messages based on other validation directives. Some of those directives however won't allow model value to be set if they aren't valid. That's what sounds like is happening .

Comment: Thank you.  From what I can tell, if a field doesn't pass validation on ng messages, then the data for that field isn't sent back with the form data.  Instead the data for that field is set to 'undefined'.

Comment: no...has nothing to do with `ng-messages`. It has to do with how `ng-model` works with various validation directives. In turn `ng-form` processes all of those into one big object and that's what `ng-messages` is reading